# Cumulative sum over slices of array: Two approaches

Tags: python, indexing, nested-loops, cumulative-sum

I have a hard time understanding why the following two code samples produce different results:

Code 1:

```
for h in range(n_H):                       
    for w in range(n_W):               

        # Find indices
        vert_start = h * stride                  # Starting row-index for current slice 
        vert_end = vert_start + f                # Final row-index (+1) for current slice
        horiz_start = w * stride                 # Starting column-index for current slice 
        horiz_end = horiz_start + f              # Final column-index (+1) for current slice

        for c in range(n_C):
            Aux = (W[:, :, :, c] * Z[:, h, w, c, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis])
            A[:, vert_start:vert_end, horiz_start:horiz_end, :] += Aux
```

Code 2:

```
for h in range(n_H):                       
    for w in range(n_W):               

        # Find indices
        vert_start = h * stride                  # Starting row-index for current slice 
        vert_end = vert_start + f                # Final row-index (+1) for current slice
        horiz_start = w * stride                 # Starting column-index for current slice 
        horiz_end = horiz_start + f              # Final column-index (+1) for current slice

        Aux = np.zeros((m, f, f, n_CP))
        for c in range(n_C):
            Aux += (W[:, :, :, c] * Z[:, h, w, c, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis])
        A[:, vert_start:vert_end, horiz_start:horiz_end, :] += Aux
```

In both cases

- n_H, n_W, n_C, n_HP, n_WP, n_CP, m, stride and f are scalars
- W is an array of shape (f, f, n_CP, n_C)
- Z is an array of shape (m, n_H, n_W, n_C)
- A is an array of shape (m, n_HP, n_WP, n_CP)

I noticed that the two approaches yield the same result when the "index ranges"(vert_start:vert_end and horiz_start:horiz_end) are scalars instead, i.e. f=1. However, I cannot figure out why it does not work for ranges too.

Below you can find one example for which the code samples result in different ouputs:

```
np.random.seed(1)
m = 2
f = 2
stride = 1
n_C = 3
n_CP = 1
n_H = 2
n_W = 2
n_HP = 3
n_WP = 3

W = np.random.randn(f, f, n_CP, n_C)
Z = np.random.rand(m, n_H, n_W, n_C)
A = np.zeros((m, n_HP, n_WP, n_CP))
A2 = np.zeros((m, n_HP, n_WP, n_CP))

for h in range(n_H):                     
    for w in range(n_W):               

        # Find indices
        vert_start = h * stride                  # Starting row-index for current slice 
        vert_end = vert_start + f                # Final row-index (+1) for current slice
        horiz_start = w * stride                 # Starting column-index for current slice 
        horiz_end = horiz_start + f              # Final column-index (+1) for current slice

        for c in range(n_C):
            Aux = (W[:, :, :, c] * Z[:, h, w, c, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis])
            A[:, vert_start:vert_end, horiz_start:horiz_end, :] += Aux

        Aux = np.zeros((m, f, f, n_CP))
        for c in range(n_C):
            Aux += (W[:, :, :, c] * Z[:, h, w, c, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis])
        A2[:, vert_start:vert_end, horiz_start:horiz_end, :] += Aux

print(A == A2)
```

Comment: I recommend unsar the function print () to understand what happens in your code or execute it step by step. Can you give examples of the values
 of inputs () when the error occurs?

Comment: I have edited my question and added an example of parameter values for which the two approaches provide different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it appears that there is no difference when printing A and A2, this is only due to the way Python displays the results. Outputting (A - A2) shows that there is indeed a small difference at the positions labeled "False". However, the difference is of dimension e-16. So it simply is a rounding error.